# How to correctly pass structures to functions

Tags: c

So the question I'm working on has me creating a structure with 5 elements: id number, name, department, course, and year. I have to write a function that prints the names of people with certain years and a function that prints all data based on id number input.

When I type in 2020 as an input I get a segmentation fault. What could be causing this?

````
#include <stdio.h>

struct stud
    {
        int id;
        char name[50];
        char dep[50];
        char course[50];
        int year;
    };
void printbyyear(struct stud *student,size_t sz, int a);
void printspecific(struct stud *b,size_t sz, int a);

int main()
{
    int yr,num,b;
    struct stud students[]={
        {1,"Jon","math","calc",2019},
        {2,"Tim","Language arts","calc",2020},
    };
    printf("Input year to search for:");
    scanf("%d",&yr);
    printbyyear(students, sizeof(students),yr);
    printf("Input ID # to search for:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printspecific(students, sizeof(students),num);
    return 0;
}

void printbyyear(struct stud *b,size_t sz, int a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {
        if (b[i].year==a)
        {
            printf("%d %c %c %c %d",b[i].id,b[i].name,b[i].dep,b[i].course,b[i].year);
        }
    }
}

void printspecific(struct stud *b,size_t sz, int a)
{
    printf("%d %c %c %c %d",b->id,b->name,b->dep,b->course,b->year);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: The variables of type `struct stud` that you've created are `b1` and `b2`.  One of those is what you should be passing as the first argument to `printbyyear()`---not `struct stud`, which is not a variable but the name of a type.

Comment: typo? `printbyyear(struct stud,yr);`

Comment: Also, it is more common to pass large structs by address.

Comment: `scanf("%d...", & b[i].id, ... `.  That is, use `&b[i].id` instead of `b[i].id`.  Similarly in other places where appropriate.

Comment: .... but if you are reference `b[i]` at all, then I would expect to see the function signature as `void printbyyear( struct stud *b....)` and the structure's address should be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your programs.

1. `printbyyear(struct stud,yr);`

that is not how you call a function with `struct` variable, change it as `printbyyear(b1,yr);` or `printbyyear(b2,yr);`

2. you are not using array of structs , so you don't need to use loops at all for your code.

```
if (b.year == a)
{
     printf("%d %s %s %s %d",b.id,b.name,b.dep,b.course,b.year);
}
```

finally if you want to store multiple records, then use array of struct's like below.

```
struct stud students[]= {
                                {2,"Tim","Language arts","calc",2020},
                                {1,"Jon","math","calc",2019}
                        };
```

and call it as below ( `sizeof(students)/sizeof(students[0])` ) gives the number of elements you have in your structure)

```
printbyyear(students, sizeof(students)/sizeof(students[0]), yr);
```

now you can use loops for printing because you passed an array

```
void printbyyear(struct stud *student, size_t sz, int y)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {
        if (student[i].year == y)
        {
            printf("%d %s %s %s %d",student[i].id,student[i].name,student[i].dep,student[i].course,student[i].year);
        }
    }
}
```

and you declaration of function should be as below

`void printbyyear(struct stud *b,size_t size, int a);`

Comment: So now the program compiles, which is an improvement, but now after I enter my desired year it just gives a segmentation fault. Is something not pointing to the right spot?

Comment: edit your original post with changes you have done

Comment: I edited the code and reviewed what I've done and i don't know where the code is getting stopped

Comment: you have not copied the code properly, just look at `printbyyear(students, sizeof(students),yr);` and how i called 2) format specifiers are not updated in `printf` inside your functions use `%s` instead of `%c` 3) for printing by `id` you have to compare the same way as you are comparing in `if (b[i].year==a)`, but instead of `year`, it should be `id`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that here

```
if (b[i]stud.year==a)
```

You are trying to access `b1`, `b2` and any other possible student. To do that you need an array of type `struct stud`

```
struct stud b[5];
```

Now your `if` condition makes sense. The function call should be:

```
printbyyear(b,yr);
```

And the declaration

```
void printbyyear(struct stud *b, int a)
```

Also since you initialize only two students, i.e. only two elements of your array, the `for` loop should be `for(i=1;i<=2;i++)` with a 2 not a 5.

Accessing uninitialised elements or accessing an array out of bounds will result in an undefined behaviour.

Comment: While this answers explains how to access `b[i]` it does not describes how to prevent reading or writing beyond the array limits. The function should also receive as argument the array size (the number of `struct stud` items in it, `5` in this case) and it should make sure `i` is inside the array limits before reaching `b[i]`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am going to add something about it, even if that thing of accessing an array out of bounds is a matter of arrays, which is not what the OP asked for. But yes, why not to just help him in any way?

Answer (score 0):

*Correct* is an ambiguous term, so I will just say this method is one that I prefer:

Passing the *address of* an object of significant size is advantageous in that the *address of* that object is going to be smaller than the object itself.

So given for example your struct (typedefed for readability) I would make the following modifications (i.e. to pass by reference to the address of the object.)

Read in-line comments and note corrections in code:

```
    typedef struct 
    {
        int id;
        char name[50];
        char dep[50];
        char course[50];
        int year;
    }stud_s;


//modify to accept pointer, and add size of array argument
void printbyyear(stud_s *s, int yr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    int yr,num;
    
    stud_s b1[] = {   {1,"Jon","math","calc",2019},
                        {2,"Tim","Language arts","calc",2020},
                        {3,"Jen","the arts","calc",2021},
                        {4,"Bob","painting arts","calc",2022},
                        {5,"jed","numeric arts","calc",2023}
                    };
    size_t size = sizeof(b1)/sizeof(b1[0]);
    
    printf("Input year to search for:");
    scanf("%d",&yr);
    printbyyear(b1,yr, size);// b1 is a pointer to array of struct here.
    printf("Input ID # to search for:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    return 0;
}

void printbyyear(stud_s *b, int a, size_t size)
{
    int i=0;
    //for(i=1;i<=5;i++)//results in out of bounds access to array
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) //change magic number for actual size of array           
    {
        if (b[i].year==a)
        {
            //fix format specifiers
            printf("%d %s %s %s %d\n",b[i].id,b[i].name,b[i].dep,b[i].course,b[i].year);
            //printf("%d %c %c %c %d",b[i].id,b[i].name,b[i].dep,b[i].course,b[i].year);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```